# A synonym for teleport?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I looked at the thesaurus and wasn't satisfied with any of them. [beam, emit, send, transmit]

I'm looking for a word that means move to another place instantly - preferably less than 3 syllables.

Thanks

Edit: Thanks everyone for your suggestions

Comment: *Beam me up, Scotty*

Comment: transubstantiate, perhaps. :)

Comment: "move to another place instantly"—how about "instamove". :p

Comment: What's wrong with *teleport*?

Comment: @Armstrongest, *transubstantiate* means to convert from one substance to another (generally, the wine/bread of the [Eucharist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharist) into the literal blood/flesh of Jesus). Some people consider it to simultaneously be wine/bread and blood/flesh, but I don't think there's any notion of it being in two places at once.

Comment: @MichaelS Yep. It's the converstion of a piece of matter into something else... which some could argue is the only real way to teleport. Rather than send the person, you're essentially sending instructions to form a copy and erasing the original. At least that's how I understand the current state of teleportation. ( It was a bit tongue-in-cheek... and way more than two syllables )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the verbs ***tesser*** or ***wrinkle***, from the children's book *[A Wrinkle in Time](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf41)*, if you're looking for a niche word.

I've never heard of *jaunte*, although it's clearly based on the word *jaunt*, which just means "a short journey". Without having seen in used in this context, I would assume the author meant the latter word. Alternately, it looks like something French whose meaning I wouldn't begin to guess at.

Similarly, people who've never read *A Wrinkle in Time* might have no idea about *tesser* or *wrinkle*. *Tesser* immediately brings up thoughts of [tesseracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) and higher-dimension thinking, but many people wouldn't even make that connection, let alone assume you're talking about teleporting.

Anyone familiar with the [paper-folding analogy](http://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_blackholes_wormholes.html) of wormholes might immediately make the connection between a *fold* and a *wrinkle*, but then they might not.

If you're doing some kind of worldbuilding, you can use pretty much anything you want as long as you explain it, either as a narrator or in-character. Terms like *gate*, *rift*, *slip*, *slide*, *shift*, *jump*, *port*, *pop*, *warp*, *fold* or *beam* can all be used in this context as local lingo for faster-than-light or instantaneous travel.

If you're using the term in a simpler context, I'd stick with *teleport* (a door between distant places, or the act of stepping through said door) or possibly *translocale/locate* (one location that exists in multiple distant areas, or the act of stepping between distant areas via the translocale). Note that *translocate* also has the more common meaning of just moving something between two places, and doesn't always imply instantaneous transport.

You could also use *transport*, but it suffers from the same problem as translocate; it normally just means to move something between two places at normal speeds. In fact, the only place I've heard the term *transport* used for instantaneous travel is in Star Trek or parodies thereof, and even there it isn't instant. Normal matter gets turned to light or faster-than-light particles which move very fast, and looks like teleportation at human time scales, but is really just very fast travel.

Answer (score 7):

The canonical verb is ***[jaunte](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jaunte)***, as established in Alfred Bester's *[The Stars My Destination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination#Speculative_science)*.

Comment: Excellent, @John Lawler. It's time I re-read it.

Comment: I'd forgotten that one! But we do also say that [an electron **jumps** to a (higher/lower orbit)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+electron+jumps+to+a%22), and that's not exactly "sci-fi" - I think they really do reckon the electron moves "instantly" (insofar as it was ever in one particular place to start with).

Comment: PS. In case British readers don't follow that, in the UK, Bester's novel was titled 'Tiger, Tiger'.

Answer (score 3):

The Church calls it *translocation* when it is a miracle, implying by backformation that *translocate* should be a word.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use `transport` After all, that's what transporters do.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Transport is perfectly valid as an alternative.